# Django test: How to get the html string from a HTTPResponseRedirect object

Tags: django, testing, httpresponse

I have a test in which the view redirects using HttpRepsonseRedirect(). In my test I pass a dict to a POST request which goes through this HttpResponseRedirect.

```
data = {...data...}
response = self.client.post(url, data)
```

How do I check if strings are in the response HTML? I cant do:

```
self.assertContains(response, 'my_string')
```

or

```
self.assertIn(response, 'my_string')
```

Is there a way of accessing the HTML as a string from this response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the argument `follow=True` to the test client to make it follow redirects. Then you can use `assertContains` to check for the expected content.

```
data = {...data...}
response = self.client.post(url, data, follow=True)
self.assertContains(response, 'my_string')
```

Answer (score 4):

Django provides an [assertion function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertInHTML), `TestCase.assertInHtml(needle, haystack)` that you can use to assert that a given `needle`(your HTML string) is in the `haystack` (the HTML from the response object). Beware, that the HTML content of an `HttpResponse` is provided as a byte string in the  `content` attribute of the response object, so you will need to decode it like this:

```py
self.assertInHtml('my_string', response.content.decode())
```

Comment: Thank you, I have been stuck for 3 hours,  I used `assertInHtml` with `str(response.content)` and the tests didn't passing thanks to `response.content.decode()`.